# rails cancan first time use with roles_mask

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

First time use of cancan with roles_mask.  Keep getting `undefined method '&' for "1":String` In edit view.

form.html.erb

```
<% for role in User::ROLES %>
      <%= check_box_tag "user[roles][]", role, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
      <%=h role.humanize %><br />
    <% end %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", "" %>
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :firstname, :lastname, :username, :roles
    ROLES = %w[admin manager employee banned]

      def roles=(roles)
        self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.sum
      end

      def roles
        ROLES.reject do |r|
          ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
        end
      end

      def role?(base_role)
        ROLES.index(base_role.to_s) <= ROLES.index(role)
      end

      def is?(role)
        roles.include?(role.to_s)
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you defining roles_mask somewhere as "1"?  The roles accessor is dying because the bitwise & operator is not defined for the string class.  You may need to do roles_mask_var.to_i where you are calling the roles setter.

ian.

Comment: My bad.  went "string" crazy on my migration and roles_mask was a string instead of an integer.